# Github pages, using jekyll to covert two markdown pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am very new to this, and I want to build a very simple personal website.
I used the Github pages and jekyll. I have two markdown pages that I need to convert to html through jekyll. My folder structure is:

```
/docs
--index.md
--resources.md
--_config.yml
```

For some reason, initially only index.md is converted to html.
After reading some posts, I added the title below, but now it shows 404.

```
---
title: Title
---
```

My link from index to resources is simply below:

```
<a href= "resources.md">Resources</a>
```

What else should I do/try to make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're running `bundle exec jekyll build` inside the `docs` directory, I don't see any reason this wouldn't work. Are you getting errors in your terminal? Can you add your project to a GitHub repo? If not, perhaps you could add the contents of your `_config.yml` to the question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I build this directly in the github website, and not from terminal; my _config.yml is below:
theme: jekyll-theme-minimal

Comment: ok I think I finally got this to work by adding the permalink, followed tutorial here. Thanks!! https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-content-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll

Answer (score 0):

After reading this:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-content-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll

I noticed that I should have added the permalink in the front-matter like:

```
title: "PAGE TITLE"
permalink: /resources/
```

Hope this can help those who just started using jekyll with GitPages and markdown as well.